# How to map first row(attribute name) in excel file with the all cell values in java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have tried the following code to get first row of value(attribute name) in excel file mapping with other specific cell values i.e attribute-name=value (e.g age=30-39,meno-pause=premeno,.. etc). And then, the mapping values are add ArrayList.
But no correct output please help me!

> attribute-name>> age,meno-pause,tumor-size,inv-nodes,node-caps,deg-malig,breast,breast-quard,irradiat,Class

-------***

Values>>

```
30-39,premeno,30-34,0-2,no,3,left,left_low,no,no-recurrence-events
40-49,premeno,20-24,?,no,2,right,right_up,no,no-recurrence-events
40-49,premeno,20-24,0-2,no,2,left,left_low,no,no-recurrence-events
60-69,ge40,15-19,0-2,no,2,right,left_up,no,no-recurrence-events
40-49,premeno,0-4,0-2,no,2,right,right_low,no,no-recurrence-events
60-69,ge40,15-19,0-2,no,2,left,left_low,no,no-recurrence-events
50-59,premeno,25-29,0-2,no,2,left,left_low,no,no-recurrence-events
60-69,ge40,20-24,0-2,no,1,left,left_low,no,no-recurrence-events
40-49,premeno,50-54,0-2,no,2,left,left_low,no,no-recurrence-events
40-49,premeno,20-24,0-2,no,2,right,left_up,no,no-recurrence-events
```

Java Code

```
public class Excel {

    private static Scanner sc;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<String> transactions = new ArrayList<String>();
        String str1,str2=null;
        String addArray = null;
        sc = new Scanner(new File("bc_dataset.csv"));
        str1=sc.nextLine();
          while (sc.hasNextLine())
            {
                String str2 = sc.nextLine();
                transactions.add(str1 + "=" + str2);
                System.out.println(transactions);
            }
    }
```

Comment: What is the first line of the `csv` file ?

Comment: It is {age,meno-pause,tumor-size,inv-nodes,node-caps,deg-malig,breast,breast-quard,irradiat,Class}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below changes. Explanation is in comments.

```
public class Excel {

        private static Scanner sc;
        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            List<String> transactions = new ArrayList<String>();
            String str1,str2=null;
            String addArray = null;
            sc = new Scanner(new File("bc_dataset.csv"));
            str1=sc.nextLine();
            String []attributes = str1.split(","); // split the attributes by `,`. This will return array of String [age,meno-pause,tumor-size,...]
              while (sc.hasNextLine())
                {
                    String str2 = sc.nextLine();
                    String []linesplit = str2.split(","); // split the line by `,`. This will return array of String [30-39,premeno,30-34....]
                    // loop over both arrays and add them together 
                    for(int i = 0; i<attributes.length; i++){
                       finalline = finalline+attributes[i]+"="+linesplit[i]+",";
                    }
                    // this will add extra `,` in the end of string which I leave on you to escape 
                    transactions.add(finalline); // add final line to the list
                    System.out.println(transactions);
                }
        }
```

Comment: @candylayy Could you please accept the answer by clicking on gray tick mark visible against my answer if the answer is acceptable ?